# Idiomatic way to do max for Option<number> in Rust

Tags: rust, option-type

I have a number in `Option`. I need to replace it with max value of it and some other value, or use that other value if my number is `None`.

I wrote a function to do so:

```rust
fn max(a: Option<u32>, b: u32) -> Option<u32> {
    if a.is_some() {
        Some(std::cmp::max(a.unwrap(), b))
    } else {
        Some(b)
    }
}
```

But I can't stop thinking there is a better and concise way to do so using methods of `Option`. Can you help me?

Comment: A short version: `max(a.unwrap_or(0), b)`. (You can also use `u32::MIN` if you want to future-proof the code against a type change to `i32`.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Max:**

`Option<T>` [implements](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#impl-Ord) `Ord` when `T` implements `Ord`, so it is possible to implement your function like this:

```rust
fn max(a: Option<u32>, b: u32) -> Option<u32> {
    std::cmp::max(a, Some(b))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=867bade4e1f7e4e000d4f5c8d1c7bd0c)

---

Please note that:

> For every `T: Ord`,  `Some<T>`  is greater than `None`, which
> satisfies your requirement.

This is not documented but we can prove:

Since `Ord` types form a [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order). This means they need to be transitive; if `None` is lesser than the `Some(MIN)` then `None` will be lesser than any other value in the set(`Option<T>`), because `Some(MIN)` is lesser than any value in the set except `None`

```rust
assert!(Some(std::i64::MIN) > None);
```

---

**Min:**

You can also extend `std::cmp::min` by adding extra `or`, this would also work for the `max` case but it is not needed since there will be additional check and extra copy of the value `b` comparing the solution for `max`.

```rust
fn min(a: Option<u32>, b: u32) -> Option<u32> {
    std::cmp::min(a.or(Some(b)), Some(b))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c848871514db5f11f7d3e7d009792b1e)

Comment: It's really clever! Too sad, it works only for `max` (in my code I have both min and max having the same `Option<number>` structure.

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin thanks, I've added alternative solution for `min`,  hope it helps.

Comment: Another way to do `min` is `std::iter::once(b).chain(a).max()`, (and cross your fingers and hope the optimizer has your back)

Answer (score 5):

Use [`map`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map):

```rust
fn max(a: Option<u32>, b: u32) -> Option<u32> {
    a.map(|v| std::cmp::max(v, b))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d2fe36007e48a1ebae9d57d271be50fc)

Or [`map_or`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or) to default the unwraped term:

```rust
fn max(a: Option<u32>, b: u32) -> Option<u32> {
    a.map_or(Some(b), |v| Some(std::cmp::max(v, b)))
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9555d26c766d086bfaf3f2cb1d5ebd1a)

For which you actually do not need the returned `Option`:

```rust
fn max(a: Option<u32>, b: u32) -> u32 {
    a.map_or(b, |v| std::cmp::max(v, b))
}
```

Comment: First example does work if `a` is `None`.

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin, yeah, was getting ready the map_or one

Comment: The second one does, thank you. `Some(a.map_or(b, |v| std::cmp::max(v, b)))`

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin, for the second case mind that you do not really need the option since you are guaranteed to have a returned value.

Comment: I need to save it back to a field of a struct, so, Option is mandatory, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

*...for those functional programming nerds...*
Just another way to do it using monad properties, maybe this helps you to understand monads, it allows that given a  `Thing<A>` apply a function `A -> Thing<B>` to get a `Thing<B>`:

```hs
and_then :: Thing<A> -> (A -> Thing<B>) -> Thing<B>
```

```rust
fn max(a: Option<u32>, b: u32) -> u32 {
    a.and_then(|v| Some(std::cmp::max(v, b))).unwrap_or(b)
}
```

Comment: And than I need to put it back into Option. With all respect to monads, I don't believe your code is any more readable or concise than original.

Comment: I know, just adding a different approach